# Error while connection Visual Studio to Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to connect my Visual Studio to a repository in Azure DevOps. I did run the command of the proxy config on the git bash and it worked. I tried to manage connections and connect to a repository. It ended up throwing an error message inside Visual Studio "installation" that's the whole message .

I can't find anything related to it online. What can I try next?

Comment: Could you provide the error message? According to it we can give better answers. Thank you!

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT unfortunately not yet. If I reached anything I'm going to post it here.

Comment: @2766, So, you still have this issue? If there is any detailed error message you could share to us? Or what have you done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the message was "installation". I solved it by removing the Git again and download it then run the proxy config command and restart the visual studio. Tadaaa, It worked like a charm .

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your command for the proxy config you ran in your git bash is something like this
`git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port`

If you try to connect your Visual Studio with your Azure DevOps project this is more than pure git. So just setting the proxy for git will not work. Consider updating your Visual Studio proxy settings as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-network-related-errors-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

> Error while connection Visual Studio to Azure Devops

To resolve the connection Visual Studio to Azure Devops behind the proxy, you could [set an Environment Variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) called "`HTTP_PROXY`".

It follows the same configuration scheme as Team Explorer. After setting the variable, restart Visual Studio if you had it open when changing the environment.

Check the document [Set Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh272656(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (Team Explorer Everywhere) for some more details.

Certificate source: [Configure Git for Visual Studio to use a proxy server](https://jessehouwing.net/visual-studio-git-configure-proxy/).

Hope this helps.